# Basis of a covering space

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces

I have a question regarding covering space.

Let $\pi : E \rightarrow X$ be a covering. Is it true that the connected components $U_i$ of the counter image $\pi^{-1}(U)$ of $U$ varying among the evenly covered neighborhoods of $X$, form a basis for the existing topology on $E$?

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not use connected components for this purpose, not if the space $X$ fails to be locally connected.

Instead of connected components, choose a particular even covering $\pi^{-1}(U) = \coprod_{i \in I} V_i$ of each evenly covered open set $U$. The set of all such $V_i$'s, as you vary $U$ over an evenly covered basis for $X$, forms a basis for $E$.

Comment: Sorry, I am little bit confused, but the $U_i$ I mention are the same as yours $V_i$, since for an evenly covered $U$, one has $\pi^{-1}(U) = \coprod_i U_i$, where the $U_i$ are the connected component of $\pi^{-1}(U)$.

Comment: No, that is not a correct description of the $V_i$'s if the space $X$ is not locally connected. On the other hand, if $X$ is locally connected, then that is fine.

Comment: Think, for example, of the Cantor set $C$ and the identity map $i : C \to C$. This is a covering map, because each open subset $U \subset C$ is evenly covered, with the even covering by a single open set $i^{-1}(U)=U$. But the connected components of $U$ are the individual points.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!